# Radio button "yes" if checked, "no" if unchecked

Tags: php, forms

Good afternoon, I having difficulty with the radio button on a form I have created. I found a similar problem on here, but with having limited php coding experience, I was unable to correctly code it or my form. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php 
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$procedure = $_POST['procedure'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$policybox = null;
foreach($_POST['policy'] as $policy){
if(isset($policy)){
    $policybox .= "Yes\r\n";
} else{
    $policybox .= "No\r\n";
}
} 

$formcontent="From: $firstname $lastname \nEmail: $email \nPhone: $phone \nType of Procedure: $procedure \nDate Requested: $date \nI have read and understood the policies: $policybox \nMessage: $message";
$recipient = "sales@domainname.com";
$subject = "Appointment Form from DomainName.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header('Location: appointments.php');
?>
```

The field Im trying to get to show up is:

```
<div class="form_info cmsms_radio">
                                        <div class="check_parent">
                                            <input type="radio" name="policy" value="Yes" />                
                                            <label for="policy">I have read and understand the <a href="refund-policy.php">Refund Policy</a> and <a href="cancellation-policy.php">Cancellation Policy</a></label>
                                        </div>
```

Im sure its something small Im missing, but like I said Im not very experienced with php yet.

Comment: You don't need to use a `foreach` on a single radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$_POST['policy']` variable isn't going to be an array (based on your code), therefore you do not need to iterate over it.  You can simply test the form value itself.

Replace your `foreach` with the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['policy']) && $_POST['policy'] == "Yes") {
    $policybox .= "Yes\r\n";
} else{
    $policybox .= "No\r\n";
}
```